# Positioning two CSS images next to each other and not below

Tags: html, css

Im busy making this website homepage but have come across a problem which must be so simple but i just can't find it anywhere, I want to position both 'topskin' and 'topskin2' next to each other, i will also be adding more which i also want next to each other.

Here is the HTML :

```
<div id="secondinner">
<div id="topskin">
</div>

<div id="topskin2">
</div>
This is the third segment to the home page.
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#secondinner {
padding-top:300px;
width:980px;
margin:0 auto;
}


#topskin {
background-image:url(images/topskins/1f.png);
background-size:110px;
height:220px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:150px;

}

#topskin2 {
background-image:url(images/topskins/1f.png);
background-size:110px;
height:220px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:150px;
}
```

Just to inform you, i have tried float:left, on both elements, and instead of going below each other they simply disappear.

Comment: What about `float:left;display:inline-block;` for children and `overflow:hidden` for parent?

Comment: Thanks every one these worked, yet i still have a problem that my surrounding wrapper (which is the white background) does not stretch and go around the inline images

Comment: Here is an example of what it looks like now, http://imgur.com/KSOpWU4

Comment: As you can see by the image above the surrounding wrapper is only stretching around the 'This is the......' text, and it is totally ignoring the two images

Comment: Maybe, you should better create interactive `JSFiddle`

Comment: Sure ill make one now,

Comment: @M1K1O Ive made the JSfiddle, I'm just wondering where the save button is, do i need to make an account ?

Comment: I noticed it also yesterday. It has disappeared, you should sign up.

Comment: Ah right strange they changed it, Thanks, sorry about that

Comment: The website looks a but messed up as i have not filled out the javascript section, but the two boxed at the bottom give you the general idea of the problem http://jsfiddle.net/bjbear123/u42vh3rL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at your image, your element are floarting out of div. You must set `overflow:hidden` to their parent to avoid that.

```
#secondinner {
  overflow:hidden
}
```

Each child must be floated:

```
#topskin, #topskin2 {
  float:left
}
```

Comment: Thats absolutely perfect, Thanks for taking the time to help me, Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways doing that.

1. Use float:left on #topskin and topskin2
2. use display: inline-block; on #topskin and topskin2

Answer (score 0):

Try to use float.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/richasingh/ffqgm9n1/5/)**

```
#secondinner {
    padding-top:300px;
    width:980px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#topskin {
    background-image:url(images/topskins/1f.png);
    background-size:110px;
    height:220px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:150px;
    border:2px solid;
    float:left;
}
#topskin2 {
    background-image:url(images/topskins/1f.png);
    background-size:110px;
    height:220px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:150px;
    border:2px solid;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks every one these worked, yet i still have a problem that my surrounding wrapper (which is the white background) does not stretch and go around the inline images

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add `display: inline-block`..

With this code, even if you add as many as images with div having class `img-container` they will appear inline.

Here's working code for you.

```
<div id="secondinner">
<div id="topskin" class="img-container">
</div>

<div id="topskin2" class="img-container">
</div>
This is the third segment to the home page.
</div>
```

`img-container` is class having following css property.

```
.img-container{
     display:inline-block;   
}
```

JSFIDDLE DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/5mnxqphx/